# Spring framework - Data not display in view page

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web

**no errors display in my view...but when it run it gives the value as '0'. my database table name is 'categories'.it has a value like 'category_l dummy' for the column .But in the view display as a 0...please help me to slove this...**

This is my model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class CategoriesModel implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) //for autonumber
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String category1;
    @Column
    private String desccategory1;

    public CategoriesModel() {
    }

    public CategoriesModel(
            int id,
            String category1, String desccategory1) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.category1 = category1;
        this.desccategory1 = desccategory1;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategory1() {
        return category1;
    }

    public void setCategory1(String category1) {
        this.category1 = category1;
    }

    public String getDesccategory1() {
        return desccategory1;
    }

    public void setDesccategory1(String desccategory1) {
        this.desccategory1 = desccategory1;
    }
```

This is my Dao class

```
public interface CategoriesDao {

    public void add(CategoriesModel categories);
    public void edit(CategoriesModel categories);
    public void delete(int id);

    public CategoriesModel getCategoriesModel(int id);

    public List getAllCategoriesModel();
}
```

This is my Dao impl class

```
@Repository
public class CategoriesDaoImpl implements CategoriesDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

    @Override
    public void add(CategoriesModel categories) {
        session.getCurrentSession().save(categories);
        //this "categories" is a table name
    }

    @Override
    public void edit(CategoriesModel categories) {
        session.getCurrentSession().update(categories);
        //this "categories" is a table name
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        session.getCurrentSession().delete(getCategoriesModel(id));
        //this "id" is a feild in Model
    }

    @Override
    public CategoriesModel getCategoriesModel(int id) {
        return (CategoriesModel) session.getCurrentSession().get(CategoriesModel.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List getAllCategoriesModel() {
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from CategoriesModel").list();
         //this "CategoriesModel" is a its model name
    }
```

This is my service class

```
public void add(CategoriesModel categories);

    public void edit(CategoriesModel categories);

    public void delete(int id);

    public CategoriesModel getCategoriesModel(int id);

    public List getAllCategoriesModel();
```

This is my service impl class

```
@Service
public class CategoriesServiceImpl implements CategoriesService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriesDao CategoriesDao;

    @Transactional
    public void add(CategoriesModel categories) {
        CategoriesDao.add(categories);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void edit(CategoriesModel categories) {
        CategoriesDao.edit(categories);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        CategoriesDao.delete(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public CategoriesModel getCategoriesModel(int id) {
        return CategoriesDao.getCategoriesModel(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List getAllCategoriesModel() {
        return CategoriesDao.getAllCategoriesModel();
    }
```

this is my controller class

```
@Autowired
    private CategoriesService CategoriesService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map) {
        CategoriesModel categories = new CategoriesModel();
        //Create a new object from details Model
        map.put("category", categories);
        //new created object is assign and view name

        map.put("categoriesList", CategoriesService.getAllCategoriesModel());
        //view feild assign list in view page
        System.out.println(categories);
        return "allcategories";

        //return page(view name)
    }
```

this is my view

```
 <c:forEach items="${categoriesList}" var="category">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="category">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
                    <a href="" target="_self"><img src="images/properties/cars.png" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="link">
                            <p>${category.category1}</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where do you get 0?

Comment: in the view...I dont have an idea..please help me to slove this...when I enter the  <p>${category.id}</p> it gives '0'. but when I gives <p>${category.category1}</p> it returns no value..please help me.....if u can please check the codes...I'm newer to spring cording

Comment: @NipunVidarshana Are you sure you are getting the list from query? Can you print and see in console?

Comment: could u try `Model model` indtesd of `Map<String, Object> map`, I don't know how we access `Map<String, Object> map` in view **OR** whether is this possible ?

Comment: How i try Model model for map...i dont have an idea...please tell me

Comment: @ soorapadman how to check i'm getting from query list..i'm newer to spring...

Comment: @NipunVidarshana did you fix this problem?

Comment: @ cralfaro no sir ....i'm so sad....hmmmmm..i want to fix this code..please hellp me someone

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
    private CategoriesService CategoriesService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String setupForm(Model model) {
        CategoriesModel categories = new CategoriesModel();
        //Create a new object from details Model
        model.addAttribute("category", categories);
        //new created object is assign and view name

        model.addAttribute("categoriesList", CategoriesService.getAllCategoriesModel());
        //view feild assign list in view page
        System.out.println(categories);
        return "allcategories";

        //return page(view name)
    }
```